# UITableViewCell property doesn't show on view during certain ways of setting the property

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

Basically, when assigning the property of my image view to a property in my data model it doesn't work. However, if I explicitly set it as a new UIImageView it works fine.

cell.imageview = obj.struct.imageview

Doesn't work, have to click cells to see the images or wait 10-20 seconds

cell.imageview = UIImageView(UIImage(named: "name.jpg"))

Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a correct way to set image. You should read some book / article about iOS development again before ask more questions. The right way is set UIImage.

> cell.imageview.image = obj.struct.image

or

> cell.imageview.image = UIImage(named: "name.jpg")